# Django - how to assign custom object as model property and get that model instance in that object?

Tags: python, django

I want to separate some logic from model and group it in a property, just like Django does with model managers (`object` property). I fact, something like `ForeignKey` but without database representation.

I have something like this:

```
class Remote(object):
    def __init(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.post = ... # how to get to post instance?

    def synchronize(self):
       # this function requires Post object access
       print(self.post.name)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    remote = Remote()

...

for post in Post.objects.all():
    post.remote.synchronize()
```

**Question**

How to modify above code to get access to `Post` object in `Remote` object?

**Additional question**

Is it possible to determine if `Remote` object has been called from `Post` instance (`post.remote...` – like above) or `Post` class (`Post.remote...`)?

Comment: You have to write `Remote` as a descriptor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want here can be achieved with [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

In order for it to work, you need to define a `__get__` method in your class that you want to be accessible as an attribute of another class.

A simple example for your case will look like this:

```
class Remote:
    def __init__(self, post)
        self.post = post

    def synchronize(self):
       print(self.post.name)


class RemoteDescriptor:
    def __get__(self, obj):
        if not obj:
            return self
        remote = getattr(obj, '_remote', None)
        if not remote:
            remote = Remote(obj)
            obj._remote = remote
        return remote


class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    remote = RemoteDescriptor()
```

**Explanation**:

In the above code, every time you call an attribute remote of your `Post` model, `__get__` method of the `RemoteDescriptor` will be invoked. First check for obj is to make sure that descriptor is called from other object, not directly. Two classes Remote and RemoteDescriptor are needed here in order for you to be able to add custom methods inside your descriptor accessible using dot (e.g. `post.remote.calculate()`)

Note also that I am placing the instance of `Remote` to the dict of Post on first invokation and on all subsequent calls, object will be returned from there.

You should also check a [great article](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/) on descriptors on RealPython.